# DotNetNuke website not started in local

Tags: .net, iis, dotnetnuke

I install DotNetNuke package in local system which have windows 8 with vs 2013 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

1) In C drive i make folder websites/dnndev.me and here i unzip downloaded package.

2) Start iis manager and add new website c:\websites\dnndev.me

When i add website i check bottom check start automatically but website is not started.

I attach error screenshot[image]

Comment: Did you restarted your IIS and tested again?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai For DNN need to install external iss?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai now i got this error "This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false"."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user “IIS AppPool\DNN” has access to the folder with DNN